# don't execute for file in ls do

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I have a script that has to process some files (name beginning with AB) in a directory.
The code is :

```
for file in AB*
do
  cp ...
  ...
done
```

When there are no *.txt files in the folder the code executes anyway 1 time.
But then there are errors because I try to copy a file that doesn't exist.
How can I make that the do-command doesn't execute when the result of the ls-command is empty?

I already tried using ls, quotes an combinations > nothing gives the result I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can add a condition before:

```
if [ $(ls AB* 2>/dev/null) ]; then
     for ...

fi
```

with `2>/dev/null` you catch the errors not to be printed.

Comment: Thanks this works. But I still don't understand why de loop is executed when there are no files.

Comment: @pistach I am not sure, but note that `for` does not know what is going to do inside. `AB*` can be related to fields but also to be a parameter for a for, such as `for i in 1 2 3`. Imagine you do `for file in AB*; do echo $file; done`. This is a normal condition that will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are just **plain wrong** in Bash. Do not use them! **Please, always observe this rule:**

> **Each time you use globs in Bash, use them with either `shopt -s nullglob` or `shopt -s failglob`.**

If you observe this rule, you'll always be safe. In fact, each time you don't observe this rule, God kills a kitten.

- `shopt -s nullglob`: in this case, a non-matching glob expands to nothing. Look:

  ```
  $ mkdir Test; cd Test
  $ shopt -u nullglob # I'm explicitly unsetting nullglob
  $ echo *
  *
  $ for i in *; do echo "$i"; done
  *
  $ # Dear, God has killed a kitten :(
  $ # but it was only for demonstration purposes, I swear!
  $ shopt -s nullglob # Now we're going to save lots of kittens
  $ echo *

  $ for i in *; do echo "$i"; done
  $ # Wow! :)
  ```
- `shopt -s failglob`: in this case, Bash will raise an explicit error when a glob has no expansions. Look:

  ```
  $ mkdir Test; cd Test
  $ shopt -u nullglob # Unsetting nullglob
  $ shopt -s failglob # Setting failglob for the love of kittens
  $ echo *
  bash: no match: *
  $ # cool :) what's the return code of this?
  $ echo $?
  1
  $ # who cares, anyway? and a for loop?
  $ for i in *; do echo "$i"; done
  bash: no match: *
  $ # cool :)
  ```

Using either `nullglob` or `failglob`, you're sure to not launch random commands with uncontrolled arguments!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the bash `test` [builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html), often abbreviated as `[` , sothing like

```
if [ -f output.txt ] ; then
```

<sup>beware: spaces are important above.</sup>